# Index Error with a For-Loop and a LinkedList

Tags: java, indexing, linked-list, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to make a little game on my own to get used to Java and I just had a problem with LinkedList Index. I found a way to patch my problem but I still don't understand why my first solution is not working. This code:

```
        for (int i=0; i <= PlanetList.size(); i++)
        {
            g.drawImage(PlanetList.get(i).planetImage, PlanetList.get(i).xPos, PlanetList.get(i).yPos);
        }
```

Gave me a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException but this code:

```
            for (int i=1; i <= PlanetList.size(); i++)
        {
            g.drawImage(PlanetList.get(i-1).planetImage, PlanetList.get(i-1).xPos, PlanetList.get(i-1).yPos);
        }
```

The thing is ... my index start at 0 in both case. Why does the first gives me an Error?

Comment: Site note: please study java coding style guides. Variable names start with lower case. And: dont put the type of collection into your variable names. Maybe "planateList" is a list today - maybe it is something else tomorrow. Why don't you call it "planets" for example? That tells you about "its more than one"; but avoids "fixing" the list aspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last index in the first example is going above the allowed index range. For e.g., if the size of the list is 10, the allowed index range is [0 9]. In your first loop, it goes up to 10 (`i <= PlanetList.size()`). Change the terminal condition to `i < PlanetList.size()` to fix your issue.

The alternate is to use no indices to access elements in your list as @GhostCat has suggested:

```
for (Planet planet : PlanetList) {
    g.drawImage(planet.planetImage, planet.xPos, planet.yPos);
}
```

This is called [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) in Java

Answer (score 3):

The other solution is to simply use the index-free version to iterate "collections" that was introduced years ago:

```
for (Planet planet : PlanetList) {
  g.drawImage(planet.planetImage, planet.xPos, planet.yPos);
```

As a nice side effect, that also eliminates the code duplication that you had in your example.

And while we are at it: you are somehow violating the "tell dont ask" principle. Meaning: you are **asking** your planet object to give all the details you need to draw it. In good Object Oriented designs, you avoid that. Instead, you **tell** objects to do something. In other words: you could change your planet class to

```
 public void drawWith(Graphics g) { ...
```

With that the above code can be rewritten as:

```
for (Planet planet : ... ) { 
  planet.drawWith(g);
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU are getting the Out of bounds error because the variable i declared in the for loop is running for less than equal to condition of planetlist size as i starts from zero it will go till the linked list size but since you have given less than equal to it goes in the loop one more time therefore out of bounds exception .Just change the for loop condition to i less than linked list size it will work

Comment: Hint: try to go for shorter sentences. Things become so much easier to read and understand when you avoid those lengthy sentences go over three lines, without any punctuation. And you know, sometimes a little bit of code is simply easier to understand, too. And finally: trying to give the same answer as somebody else gave already, and just making it different by using "language" only instead of code ... simply won't get you much reputation. Compared to the answer from Vite Falcon, you answer just, sorry, sucks.